# How to return a specific value from a CSV file in R

Tags: r, quantmod, algorithmic-trading

I have a CSV file of all symbols listed on the NYSE, it is formated as follows:

```
   Symbol         Name           Last Sale
1  DDD            Company_name1  val_1
2  SSYS           Stratasys      val_2
3  GOOG           Google         val_3
4  GS             Goldman Sachs  val_4
5  AAPL           Apple          val_5
```

This is how it is displayed after importing my CSV file

```
companylist <- read.csv("~/Downloads/companylist.csv")
  View(companylist)
```

How would I go about retrieving company's specific symbol? For example if I wanted to get the symbol for the 2nd to last stock, what code should I use?
I have been searching for an answer for the past 6 hours and have looked at the documentation but cant seem to find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get that using:

```
df[2:nrow(df), 'symbol']
```

assuming the data is in `df`. For example:

```
> mtcars[2:5, "mpg"]
[1] 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I really appreciate it. Going to give this a try.

Comment: Wouldn't the "2nd to last" be `df$Symbol[nrow(df)-1]`?

Comment: Could be, I interpreted is 'second to the last', @BrandonWilliams what did you need?

Comment: I needed the second to last symbol, but I was able to figure it out with the sample code you supplied.